# prometheus cannot reach node exporter

Tags: docker, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I am learning prometheus and node_exporter and trying to set up them locally by docker.
I downloaded docker images from this https://hub.docker.com/r/prom/node-exporter and this https://hub.docker.com/r/prom/prometheus, then run them with commands:

```
docker run -d -p 9100:9100 prom/node-exporter

docker run \
    -d \
    -p 9090:9090 \
    -v /Users/person/sandbox/prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml \
    prom/prometheus
```

before running prometheus I added yml file:

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s

scrape_configs:
- job_name: 'node'
  static_configs:
  - targets: ['localhost:9100']
```

But it seems that prometheus can not reach node_export. I see metrics from node_export ->
[image]

and I see metrics from prometheus ->
[image]

but I cannot get node_export metrics from prometheus web-browser from:

[image]

By the way prometheus read yml file:
[image]

What did I wrong?

UDP: nice, it seems that localhost:9100 is unreachable
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because inside the Prometheus container, `localhost` is being resolved to the container's loopback network interface. To mitigate this, use host networking via explicitly specifying `--network=host` when starting these containers. When using host networking, Docker won't allocate container's their own networking namespace. Rather they'll share it from their host.

Alternatively, a better approach is to create an overlay network.

```sh
docker network create prom
docker network connect prom <prometheus_container_name>
docker network connect prom <node_exporter_container_name>
```

After creating and connecting containers to the overlay network, they should be accessible from one another by their Docker name <sup>[1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-ping-docker-container-from-another-container-by-name)</sup>.